# Is there a limit on input json string for aws sagemaker endpoint?

Tags: json, python-3.x, http-post, amazon-sagemaker, urllib3

I have ~5MB json string that I want to send to my endpoint. I am using boto3.client to invoke the endpoint from my python client. It throws ConnectionResetError.

```
    File "C:\Users\corona\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 600, in urlopen
    chunked=chunked)
  File "C:\Users\corona\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 354, in _make_request
    conn.request(method, url, **httplib_request_kw)
  File "C:\Users\corona\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\http\client.py", line 1229, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
  File "C:\Users\corona\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\botocore\awsrequest.py", line 92, in _send_request
    method, url, body, headers, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\corona\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\http\client.py", line 1275, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "C:\Users\corona\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\http\client.py", line 1224, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "C:\Users\corona\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\botocore\awsrequest.py", line 119, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "C:\Users\corona\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\botocore\awsrequest.py", line 203, in send
    return super(AWSConnection, self).send(str)
  File "C:\Users\corona\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\http\client.py", line 977, in send
    self.sock.sendall(data)
  File "C:\Users\corona\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\ssl.py", line 1012, in sendall
    v = self.send(byte_view[count:])
  File "C:\Users\corona\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\ssl.py", line 981, in send
    return self._sslobj.write(data)
ConnectionResetError: [WinError 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
```

Looking at the trace, I am guessing it is due to json string size. Could someone please help me how to get around this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Exceeding the payload size limit does result in a connection reset from the SageMaker Runtime service.

From the SageMaker [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/sagemaker.html):

> Maximum payload size for endpoint invocation |    5 MB

There are likely more space-efficient data formats than JSON that you could use to transmit the payload, but the available options will depend on the type of data and what model image you are using (i.e. whether Amazon-provided or a custom implementation).

Comment: Do you have any recommendations on other data formats? And what would you suggest we do if we want to stick with JSON and the JSON strings are still huge?

Comment: It's 6MB now, as the limits have changed.